# Formula for Neron Severi group of product surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves

Let $A=E\times E'$ be a surface which is a product of two elliptic curves. Then it is claimed that there is an isomorphism:
$$\mathbb Z \oplus {\rm Hom}(E, E')\oplus \mathbb Z \to {\rm NS}(A)$$ defined by $$(a,\lambda,b) \to (a-1)h+\Gamma_\lambda+(b-\deg \lambda)v,$$ where $h, v$ are horizontal and vertical divisors respectively, and $\Gamma_\lambda \subset E \times E'$ is the graph of $\lambda: E \to E'$.

Where is the reference for this result?

I notice the post 
[Neron-Severi group for product of curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222049/neron-severi-group-for-product-of-curves)
 on this site and the provided reference, but it gives no clue for such statement.

Thank you!

Comment: This is true (with appropriate modifications) for any product of curves, see Birkenhake-Lange *Complex Abelian varieties*, Theorem 11.5.1.

Comment: Thank you very much!